# How to apply between on column of type date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have simple SQL Server 2008 table that has a column `ourdate` of type `date`.

So I tried to apply `between` on the date values, but it doesn't work and gives me an error.

> *Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string*

Code like this:

```
select * 
from [ComplainsDb].dbo.dateTB 
where ourdate between '2012-11-01' AND '2012-12-31';
```

Comment: error Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Exactly: strings are not dates. Cast appropriately.

Comment: Documentation exists. Use it. Also, grammar matters. The string "plz" is not a word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a date string format that is **safe** for all language and regional settings.

The ISO-8601 format `YYYYMMDD` (note: **NO** dashes!) works in all situations - try this:

```
select * 
from [ComplainsDb].dbo.dateTB 
where ourdate between '20121101' AND '20121231';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to convert to date as below:

```
select *
from dateTB  
where ourdate between convert(datetime,'2012-11-01') and convert(datetime,'2012-12-31');

select *
from dateTB  
where convert(datetime,ourdate) between '2012-11-01' and '2012-12-31';
```

you can also use cast as below

```
select *
from dateTB  
where ourdate between cast('2012-11-01' as datetime) and cast('2012-12-31' as datetime);

select *
from dateTB  
where cast(ourdate as datetime) between '2012-11-01' and '2012-12-31';
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast your strings to dates:

```
select * 
from [ComplainsDb].dbo.dateTB 
where ourdate between Cast('2012-11-01' AS Date) AND Cast('2012-12-31' AS Date);
```